# Vim doesn't highligh syntax of links

Tags: linux, vim, symbolic-link, syntax-highlighting

I have a markdown file with the .md extension as "Personal Note.md".
I make a symbolik (soft) link of it by `ln -s` command in Linux as "Note".
I open the link with [vim](/questions/tagged/vim), it successfully traces the original file and opens it but doesn't highlight it, that is the markdown file format.

To note, it does highlight if I rename or create the **link** from the beginning with the extension `.md`, but that's no what I want to do, I don't want to add extension to the created link to keep it *shorter* and *neutral* in the user's eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could achive that by putting in the first line of the (linked) file:

```
vim: ft=markdown
```

It's *ugly*, but does the job.

Comment: The modeline will appear as a giant header when the markdown is rendered. See the latter half of my answer to put the modeline in a comment that will actually not show up (in most Markdown implementations).

Answer (score 2):

This is tricky since in this situation you prefer not to have an extension on your symlink, and there's no reliable way that I know of to automatically detect a markdown file based on its syntax (since it is after all intended to be human-readable without rendering), so `ftdetect` is out of the picture. However, you do have some options.

If you tend to make similarly named symlinks to Markdown files, you can add an `autocommand` to set the filetype for you when reading these files:

```
" Your autocmds should be defined inside a group and cleared at the start so
" that they are not defined more than once if you happen to re-source your vimrc.
" See http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html

augroup MyAutoCmds
  autocmd!

  " If you have other files that you always want to use Markdown syntax, add them
  " after 'Note' below, comma delimited. Some other ideas could be README, AUTHORS,
  " CONTRIBUTING, COPYING, etc
  autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead Note setf markdown
augroup END
```

Or, you can use a `modeline`. I do not believe that there is an *official* syntax for Markdown comments, but I've seen most support basic HTML comments. So you could append this to your Markdown file:

```
<!-- vim: set ft=markdown: -->
```

See `:h modeline` for the full details on this feature. **N.B.** this will **not** show up in the rendered Markdown, so long as the implementation supports comments, which most that I've seen do indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I think unfortunately without the extension you will have to manually set the `syntax-type` to `markdown`

```
:set syn=markdown
```

Comment: Also, this article appears to ask a similar question but I do not understand the answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371499/detect-filetype-in-vim-without-valid-file-extension

Comment: Thanks, but I know how and don't want to activate the highlighting manually. It's sad and unbelievable that there's no other way. I think vim should trace the original file and check for its extension and highlight accordingly by default or when the link lacks extensions.

Comment: You should set the syntax by setting `filetype` instead. `:set syn` will only fire the **Syntax** autocommand event, and thus wont run anything else filetype-related that would normally, such as specific formatting settings, etc